# How to ignore nested models in Swagger (ASP.Net Core 3.1)?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a complex model with multiple levels, i am using Swashbuckle.

how can I ignore related models in swagger UI? and show just the first level of the model?

See the below example, I want to ignore all relations like JobTitleVM and ICollection.

```
  public class UserVM
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }

    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public int IsActive { get; set; }

    public int JobTitleId { get; set; }
    public JobTitleVM JobTitle { get; set; }

    public int UserStatusId { get; set; }
    public UserStatusVM UserStatus { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<UserStepsVM> UserSteps { get; set; } = new List<UserStepsVM>();
  }
```

Comment: What library do you use - Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, NSwag, something else? Can you post your current model code with annotations, and how you want the model to appear in Swagger UI?

Comment: I use Swashbuckle